# When I make a matrix of points in form_load it works, but when i make it in a separate class, and make an object of it in form_load it doesn`t work

Tags: c#, winforms

So I need to make a matrix of points to spread buttons over an area, I wanted to make a class that has the matrix itself because the buttons wont appear on screen all the time and they will move in the grid etc.

anyway, here`s what the constructor for that class does:

```
 public Table()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {

                    _Grid[i, j] = new Point(i * 90, j * 90);


                }
            }
        }
```

90 is the width of the buttons

then I have a property that allows getting the grid:

```
 public Point[,] Grid
            {
            get;
            }
```

then i do the form_load like this:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Table tab = new Table();
            Point[,] grid = tab.Grid;

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {

                    Button btn =  new Button();
                    btn.Width = 88;
                    btn.Height = 88;
                    btn.Location = grid[i, j]; // it returns a NullReferernceException here
                    panel1.Controls.Add(btn);

                }
            }   
        }
```

adding the location gives me a nullreference, but if i copy the code from the constructor and make the grid matrix in form_load get it, it works.(button width and height is 88 so there`s a nice little space between the buttons)

im obviously still learning, and you can see im stuck in the very beginning of this project because i cant even make all the buttons appear where they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite a guess, but I suspect you've done something like this in Table

```
private Point[,] _Grid = new blahblahblah
public Point[,] Grid
        {
        get;
        }
```

These two things are not referring to the same thing in memory - you've filled `_Grid` and it's  valid object, but the property `Grid` is referencing some invisible backing store variable created by the compiler; having a name that is similar is not enough to wire them together

- Change Table to be like:

```
    public Point[,] Grid { get; } = new blahblahblah
```

- Delete any mention of `_Grid` in favor of `Grid`
- Change the constructor so it sets up the array via the property (thus writing values into the invisible backing field created by the compiler):

```
    Grid[i, j] = new Point(i * 90, j * 90);
```

And then retrieving `tab.Grid` will retrieve a populated thing that is not null

---

Footnote, we name private members like `_camelCase`, not `_PascalCase` and if you want to explicitly declare a read only property that gets a class member field, it would look like:

```
private Point[,] _grid = blahblahblah;
public Point[,] Grid { get { return _grid; }}
```

Or:

```
private Point[,] _grid = blahblahblah;
public Point[,] Grid { get => _grid; }
```

i.e. you have to concretely wire them together by having the prop go and get that field by name, and return it

<sub>We can get into "properties should not return arrays" another time :D</sub>

Comment: thanks, this helped. I just had to write exactly what to return with the property. idk why it sometimes works with a simple get; and set; and sometimes doesn`t, but i guess i just have to be less lazy and actually tell the code what to return lol. also, is simply making another array, giving it the array I need to return and returning that copied array a better way to do it?

Comment: *idk why it sometimes works with a simple get; and set; and sometimes doesnt* - you're confusing auto-implemented properties with fully manually implemented ones. When you make properties, either type `prop TAB TAB` or `propfull TAB TAB`

Comment: *i just have to be less lazy* -  you can use auto properties exclusively if you want. an autoprop looks like `public int Age{get;set;}` - if you want to set the age you write `blahblah,Age = 123` if you're outside the class or `Age = 123` if you're inside the class. Don't try and declare another variable and set it; the auto prop won't see it.

Comment: * is simply making another array, giving it the array I need to return and returning that copied array a better way to do it?* - [properties should not return arrays](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/210922/ca1819-properties-should-not-return-arrays-does-this-happen-only-with-arrays) - but that's a "Should", not a "Shall"